# AngularFireDatabase, Jest and unit testing firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, angularfire

I have a service that has 2 methods that return data from firebase realtime db

```
getAllProducts -> returns an observable array of products
getSingleProduct -> returns an observable single product
```

I am trying to create unit tests using Jest to mock firebase so I can test these 2 methods:

**Test file**

```js
    import {TestBed, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
    import {ProductService} from './product.service';
    import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
    import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
    import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';
    import {getSnapShotChanges} from 'src/app/test/helpers/AngularFireDatabase/getSnapshotChanges';
    import {Product} from './product';
    
    class angularFireDatabaseStub {
      getAllProducts = () => {
        return {
          db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          list: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          snapshotChanges: jest
            .fn()
            .mockReturnValue(getSnapShotChanges(allProductsMock, true))
        };
      };
      getSingleProduct = () => {
        return {
          db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          object: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          valueChanges: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(productsMock[0]))
        };
      };
    }
    
    describe('ProductService', () => {
      let service: ProductService;
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)],
          providers: [
            {provide: AngularFireDatabase, useClass: angularFireDatabaseStub}
          ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
      });
    
      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('should be able to return all products', async(() => {
        const response$ = service.getAllProducts();
        response$.subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
          expect(products).toBeDefined();
          expect(products.length).toEqual(10);
        });
      }));
    });
```

`allProductsMock` and `singleProductMock` are just dummy data in the local file.

*The error thrown is `this.db.list` is not a function.*

If I change the stub to a basic constant and not a class, then the allProducts test passes, but obviously I am then stuck testing the `getSingleProduct` method:

```js
    const angularFireDatabaseStub = {
      db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      list: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      snapshotChanges: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValue(getSnapShotChanges(allProductsMock, true))
      };
    }
```

So how can I make the stub more versatile and be able to also test the `getSingleProduct` method?

**Helper**

`getSnapshotChanges` is a helper:

```js
    import {of} from 'rxjs';
    
    export function getSnapShotChanges(data: object, asObservable: boolean) {
      const actions = [];
      const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
      for (const key of dataKeys) {
        actions.push({
          payload: {
            val() {
              return data[key];
            },
            key
          },
          prevKey: null,
          type: 'value'
        });
      }
      if (asObservable) {
        return of(actions);
      } else {
        return actions;
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I did find one way to do both tests, but it's not very DRY having to setup the TestBed twice. Surely there must be a way to combine both stubs and inject them into the TestBed only once?

```js
import {TestBed, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ProductService} from './.service';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';
import {productsMock} from '../../../../mocks/products.mock';
import {getSnapShotChanges} from 'src/app/test/helpers/AngularFireDatabase/getSnapshotChanges';
import {Product} from './product';
import {of} from 'rxjs';

const getAllProductsStub = {
  db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  list: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  snapshotChanges: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue(getSnapShotChanges(productsMock, true))
};
const getSingleProductStub = {
  db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  object: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  valueChanges: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(productsMock[0]))
};

describe('getAllProducts', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)],
      providers: [{provide: AngularFireDatabase, useValue: getAllProductsStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
  });

  it('should be able to return all products', async(() => {
    const response$ = service.getAllProducts();
    response$.subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
      expect(products).toBeDefined();
      expect(products.length).toEqual(10);
    });
  }));
});

describe('getSingleProduct', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)],
      providers: [{provide: AngularFireDatabase, useValue: getSingleProductStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
  });

  it('should be able to return a single  product using the firebase id', async(() => {
    const response$ = service.getSingleProduct('-MA_EHxxDCT4DIE4y3tW');
    response$.subscribe((product: Product) => {
      expect(product).toBeDefined();
      expect(product.id).toEqual('-MA_EHxxDCT4DIE4y3tW');
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the class approach, you are going at it a bit wrong. Nevertheless, you can use both a class or a constant. Also, you should -not- import the `AngularFireModule` in your unit tests, and definitely not initialize it. This will slow your tests down a lot, because I can imagine it needs to load in the entire `firebase` module, just for your unit tests where you are actually mocking out the firebase.

So the thing you need to mock is `AngularFireDatabase`. This class has three methods, `list`, `object`, and `createPushId`. I suspect for this test case you will only use the first two. So let's create an object which does this:

```
// your list here
let list: Record<string, Product> = {};
// your object key here
let key: string = '';

// some helper method for cleaner code
function recordsToSnapshotList(records: Record<string, Product>) {
  return Object.keys(records).map(($key) => ({
    exists: true,
    val: () => records[$key],
    key: $key
  }))
}

// and your actual mocking database, with which you can override the return values
// in your individual tests
const mockDb = {
  list: jest.fn(() => ({
    snapshotChanges: jest.fn(() => new Observable((sub) => sub.next(
      recordsToSnapshotList(list)
    ))),
    valueChanges: jest.fn(() => new Observable((sub) => sub.next(
      Object.values(list)
    )))
  })),
  object: jest.fn(() => ({
    snapshotChanges: jest.fn(() => new Observable((sub) => sub.next(
      recordsToSnapshotList({ [key]: {} as Product })[0]
    ))),
    valueChanges: jest.fn(() => new Observable((sub) => sub.next(
      Object.values({ [key]: {} })[0]
    )))    
  }))
}
```

Now it's time for initialization and implementation of the tests:

```
describe('ProductService', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  // using the mockDb as a replacement for the database. I assume this db is injected
  // in your `ProductService`
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{ provide: AngularFireDatabase, useValue: mockDb }]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
  });

  it('should be able to return all products', async((done) => {
    // setting the return value of the observable
    list = productsMock;

    service.getAllProducts().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
      expect(products?.length).toEqual(10);
      done();
    });
  }));

  it('should be able to return a single product using the firebase id', async((done) => {
    key = '-MA_EHxxDCT4DIE4y3tW';

    service.getSingleProduct(key).subscribe((product: Product) => {
      expect(product?.id).toEqual(key);
      done();
    });
  }));
});
```

By using the `list` and `key` variables, you can have multiple tests with different kinds of values to test edge cases. To see if it still returns what you expect it to return

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but it throws the error `this.db.list(...).snapshotChanges is not a function`  -> as you can see, `snapshotChanges` is not a function in your mockDb, as you have placed it inside the call to `list`. As you can see from my code, I had to make both list and snapshotChanges as 2 separate jest functions. So shouldn't `snapshotChanges` also be a `jest.fn` inside `list`?

Comment: @rmcsharry right, that was a typo on my part :) I expanded on what I use in my projects, but forgot to properly test it. I've updated the answer to make `snapshotChanges` also return `jest.fn`